# При нажатии ListPreference запустить method

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

Здраствуйте , как при нажатии на ListPreference можна запустить method не нашол решения так што задаю вапрос

```
 <PreferenceCategory android:title="General" >
    <ListPreference
         android:id="@+id/settings_clear"
        android:key="pref_cachet"
        android:numeric="integer"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Clear Cache" />
</PreferenceCategory>

ListPreference splashList = (ListPreference) PrefsActivity.this.findPreference("pref_cachet");

splashList.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }

     });
```

Comment: Чем имеено приведённый вами код вас не устраивает? Список не открывается? Или вам надо ловить нажатие на элемент списка? А возвращать `true` пробовали?

Comment: true пробовал , мне надо ловить нажатие на элемент списка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10392850/3212712) пишут, что при нажатии на элемент списка в настройках вызывается `onPreferenceClick` и `preference.getKey()` внутри метода вернёт `key` по позиции нажатого списка, который вы назначаете в `xml` в аттрибуте `android:entries`;

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
       if (preference.getKey().equals("ЗНАЧЕНИЕ_ИЗ_МАССИВА_ЗНАЧЕНИЙ_ПРИСВОЕННЫХ_В_XML")) {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), preference.getKey(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```
2. Также можно слушать не нажатие на элемент списка, а изменение настроек в `OnPreferenceChangeListener` как написано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24985733/3212712):

   ```
   final ListPreference list = (ListPreference) preference;
   lista.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
   public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

       int index = list.findIndexOfValue(newValue.toString());
       if (index != -1) 
       {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), list.getEntries()[index], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       return true;
   }
   });
   ```